# What's a good strategy for storing database snapshots in git?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I currently exclude my `development.sqlite3` from Git so that I can keep my `git status` clean unless a file has actually changed.

However when I want to checkout a much earlier version of the code that relied on a different database (and dummy data) from an earlier time I end up with code and a database that are out of sync.

Because I don't have my dev database checked into Git it's very difficult to reset that environment. I can't just rebuild the database because it needs all of the dummy information in it.

Is there a happy medium whereby I can automatically back my database up to Git on a daily basis (or perhaps each time a tag is created) but can also still exclude it in Git `.ignore`?

Answer (score 4):

If there is data you require for the database to function correctly or dummy data that helps you to develop then I think you should be using a seed file to define them.  Then when you check out the previous version you run the migrations first and then:

```
rake db:seed
```

If you update your seed file as you go to reflect the state of the database then whatever revision you check out you'll be able to generate the correct data.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't really hit the spot. I've used a similar strategy using `rake db:populate` however the populate file quickly goes out of date and isn't very much fun to update. A snapshot however would be definitively correct for that day

Comment: I understand that it's not the most fun pastime I just think it might be the "right" way (if we pretend for a minute that such a thing exists!).  Using FactoryGirl to create the objects takes a lot of the pain out of this for me as I'll be updating the factory definitions anyway which helps to reduce the overhead.